# How to program the bootloader area with JLink in an ARM Cortex M0 device

Tags: embedded, bootloader, flash-memory, segger-jlink

I'm trying to program the bootloader area of a **NUC240SE3AE** device with JLink and JFlash but I'm having  an error message:

```
"ERROR: Selected Data (0x100000 - 0x100FFF) does not fit into selected flash sectors."
```

The chip does have that area implemented but as I found out in Segger's device database:

- This device has only one flash bank,
- The one for the main application, and the second area for the bootloader is missing.

So my question is: is there a workaround for this? How to program that flash area?

Comment: Have you asked on the Segger forum?  In my experience their engineers are responsive, and Segger releases software and firmware updates (including Beta versions) pretty regularly.  https://forum.segger.com/index.php/Board/3-J-Link-Flasher-related/

Answer (score 0):

The MCU's technical reference manual in the section System Memory Map proves that the memory range `0x100000 - 0x100FFF` is not implemented.
[image: System Memory Map]

It means the config of the flasher or linker is not correct. Please provide both configs for further investigation.
Additionally, what is the firmware source?

Comment: I have been using this part for years. There is an area in the flash called LDROM between 0x001000000-0x00101FFF. Please check the manual again. It is on the page 178 in the file TRM_NUC230_240_Series_EN_Rev1.03.pdf. It can be programmed with Keil and nuvoton's own tools, but not with Segger's command line tools.

Comment: Then please provide JFlash config for further investigation. A screenshot will help too.